# Height and width of a Farseer body?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I have a body named PersonA. If PersonA collides with another body, the width and height of that body should be saved. I tried it like this but I always get error messages that "Width" and "Height" don't exist.

```
bool PersonA_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
{
//How tall and broad is the body that collided with PersonA 
float Width = fixtureB.Body.Width;
float Height = fixtureB.Body.Height;

return true;
}
```

How can I get the width and height of another body? What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bodies in Farseer have no "shape" of their own. The Body defines the position, velocity, mass, etc (basically a point-mass). Fixtures give that body a "shape" that can collide with things.

You can get the AABB (axis-aligned bounding-box) of a Fixture with `Fixture.Shape.ComputeAABB(...)`. Don't use `Fixture.GetAABB`, which is a "loose" AABB used by Farseer for collision detection.

(Note that the `LoopShape` can have multiple child shapes, see `Fixture.Shape.ChildCount`. For other shapes just use `childIndex = 0`.)

Depending on your needs, you might want to get the AABB of the transformed Fixture. For example, to get the AABB in world space, use the transform from `Body.GetTransform(...)`. Otherwise use:

```
Transform t = new Transform();
t.R.SetIdentity();
```

Note that a Body can have multiple Fixtures (`Body.FixtureList`). If this is the case, you will want to combine the AABBs of each Fixture using `AABB.Combine(...)`.

---

If you want to guarantee that the resulting width and height are equal to something you set-up at object-creation time, you may want to just use the `Body.UserData` field to store that information.

Comment: For example, if I create a rectangle, how could I store it's width and height in the Body.UserData field?

Comment: `Body.UserData` can store any `object`. So you can simply store it in that field as a `Vector2`. Then use a cast like `(Vector2)Body.UserData` to access it.

Comment: Thanx. I store the width and height in the Body.UserData field. It's the easiest way.